# Xcode Instruments - memory leak

Tags: xcode, memory-leaks, instruments

I am try to use Xcode Instruments to find memory leak
And i am sure that there is a memory leak, because deinit function have not been call and memory graph have shown the memory leak
[memery Graph Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jJgR.png)

But instruments can't show any memory leak

[Xcode Instruments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrsu7.png)

Please help

Update: Sample Code
[Sample Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHxUu.png)

Comment: There are ways of mismanaging memory that don't count as a leak. So perhaps you're doing that.

Comment: @matt Thanks for reply, i have update the sample code for it, it should be memory leak? or count as mismanage?

Comment: Yes, that's a clear retain cycle: SecondVC retains Service which retains SecondVC. I've noticed that Instruments sometimes has trouble reporting leaks that are configured very early in an object's lifetime so perhaps it misses this one for the same reason. Note also that it isn't a leak until after you pop SecondVC and it fails to go out of existence.

Comment: @matt I have already drag to dismiss the VC, it means that instrument problem which can not detect any memory leak issue?